# Apache CXF and Log4j2

Tags: java, cxf, log4j2

I run an embedded JAX-RS web service within a stand-alone Java application.  I use Apache CXF 3.3.0 with jetty as the web container.  I also use Spring to configure both Jetty and the service beans.

My app uses log4j2 and I am trying to log the URLs received by the CXF containers for trouble-shooting purposes.

I added the following annotation to the WebService interface:

```
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor")
```

Since I use Jetty and not a servlet container, the instructions documented here don't work:
[Apache CXF - General CXF Logging](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/general-cxf-logging.html)

When I run the application in eclipse, the URLs will print to the console in red.  I use red to log stderr.

But the output is not present in the log4j log file nor is the output sent to stderr or stdout when redirecting these descriptors using bash:

```
1> ${LOG_DIR}/stdout.log \
2> ${LOG_DIR}/stderr.log &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to log the `REQUEST_URL` by using `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor` with log4j2.

I was able to resolve this very easily by creating my own `InInterceptor` class.

The following class logs the incoming `REQUEST_URL` to my log4j2 appenders quite nicely:

```
public class RefDataInInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
   private static final Logger log = 
      LogManager.getLogger(RefDataInInterceptor.class);

   public RefDataInInterceptor() {
      super(Phase.RECEIVE);
   }

   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) throws Fault {
      log.info(msg.getContextualProperty(Message.REQUEST_URL));
   }
}
```

All I had to do to hook it up was replace:

```
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor")
```

With:

```
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "com.aqua.refdata.RefDataInInterceptor")
```

Here is the log4j2 output to the console and log file:

```
2019-07-12 16:13:54.811 [3710][qtp172794870-21][INFO http://localhost:9000/refdata/exec/getDBParam
eters [RefDataInInterceptor.java:19]
```